# Active view in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I just started to develop my first ios app and completely stuck with passing additional options to the view controller.

The entry controller of my app is `UITabBarController`. I set the appropriate tab in `viewDidLoad` method which is looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the view controller object to pass additional options before it starts loading. Which method should I implement in my `UITabBarController`?

Comment: additonal options mean other tab bars?

Comment: I want to pass `managedObjectContext` from my `TabBarController` to `TableViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBarController` has a property named `selectedViewController`

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController
```

is this what you are looking for?

But If you want

> pass additional options before it starts loading

you need to do it in that viewController's init method

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I told in comment above I want to pass `managedObjectContext` from `TabBarController` to `TableViewController`, but when I checking `selectedViewController` property, I see the instance of `UINavigationController`, is it possible to get the instance of selected `TableViewController`?

Comment: @InSearch `navigationController.rootViewController` should be `TableViewController`

Comment: I finally found my table view controller in `viewControllers` property of `selectedViewController`.

Comment: @InSearch `viewControllers` is a property of `UINavigationController`. You can find all the viewControllers in stack including rootViewController

Answer (score 1):

Set your tab bars with tag 0,1,2,3 respectively and use this code

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{


    switch (item.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            [self removeAllViews];


            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            [self removeAllViews];
            CategoriesVC *cvc=[[CategoriesVC alloc ]initWithNibName:@"CategoriesVC"  bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
            {

                if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
                    CGRect frame = cvc.view.frame;
                    frame.size.height = [APPDELEGATE childViewHeight];
                    cvc.view.frame = frame;
                }

            }

            break;

        }
        case 2:
        {
            [self removeAllViews];
            FavoriteVC *fvc=[[FavoriteVC alloc ]initWithNibName:@"FavoriteVC" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:fvc.view];
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
            {

                if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
                    fvc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,499);
                }

            }

            break;

        }
        case 3:
        {
            [self removeAllViews];
            ProfileVC *pvc=[[ProfileVC alloc ]initWithNibName:@"ProfileVC"  bundle:nil];

            [self.view addSubview:pvc.view];
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
            {

                if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
                    pvc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,499);
                }

            }

            break;

        }

    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm new in Objective-C programming, and not really got how this code could help me in retrieving actual view controller?